# Moving average over dataframe for each user. Python, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add a column to a dataframe with the value of a moving average coming from another column (here comes the tricky part) for each unique user.

What first comes to mind is to get a list of all unique users and iterate over all of them getting a subset of the dataframe where the user colum is equal to that user:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['user'] = [1,2,3,2,2,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,1,2,1,2,1,1]
df['value'] = [3,1,5,7,2,2,2,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,2,2,1,2,3]

unique_users = df['user'].unique()
df['rolled_value'] = 0

for user in unique_users:
    temp_df = df[df['user'] == user]
    temp_df['rolled_value'] = temp_df['value'].rolling(2).mean()
```

It doesn't work because it won't let me change the value of the column as it's a copy of a slice  from a df, but you get the idea.

This would be terribly slow, I have 10M rows and it would take forever.

I'm pretty new to python and can't come up with a fast equivalent. Is there any way I could use a lambda function here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please show us your expected output for this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you would like to do, the following should work:

```
rolled_values = df.groupby('user')['value'].rolling(2).mean().reset_index()
```

This returns a DataFrame grouped by users, the column 'level_1' contains the old Index and the 'value' column now contains the rolled average.

```
   user  level_1  value
0     1        0    NaN
1     1        5    2.5
2     1        6    2.0
3     1       14    2.0
4     1       16    2.0
5     1       18    2.0
6     1       19    2.5
7     2        1    NaN
8     2        3    4.0
9     2        4    4.5
(...)
```

Now you just need to add this column to your old DataFrame:

```
df['rolled_values'] = rolled_values.set_index('level_1')['value']

   user  value  rolled_values
0     1      3          NaN
1     2      1          NaN
2     3      5          NaN
3     2      7          4.0
4     2      2          4.5
(...)
```

Comment: Great, easy and fast. Just one thing, in the second line of code you meant values instead of rolled_mean. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! And you are right of course. I fixed it.